# How to optimize number of queries in the Django view?

Tags: python, django

I show comments in the topic detail view.  Exactly two queries happens
in this view: one to get topic and one to get comments list.  I
understand that `select_related` technique can't be used here since
there are two different querysets created in the view.  Is there any
way to decrease number of queries to one?

Application code follows below.

### app/models.py

```python
class Topic(models.Model):

    headline = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics')

class Comment(models.Model):

    headline = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=400)
    description = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments')
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='comments')
```

### app/views.py

```python
class TopicDetail(DetailView):

    queryset = Topic.objects.select_related('author').all()
    context_object_name = 'topic'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        topic = self.object
        context['comments'] = topic.comments.select_related('author').all()
        return context
```

### app/templates/app/topic_detail.html

```html
{{ topic.headline }}
{{ topic.description }}
{{ topic.created }}
{{ topic.modified }}
{{ topic.author }}
{% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment.headline }}
    {{ comment.description }}
    {{ comment.author }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can You add info why number of queries matter to Your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in pure SQL such "single" query would be hard.

Basically You would need to repeat all the topic data in each comment! Like in this pseudo code:

```
Select comment.*, topic.*
From comments
Right Join topic
```

That is massive data processing/transfer overhead. Whole operation should take more time, resources then separate queries.

If You really need it, then just write custom function in comment topic model, with pure SQL.

Comment: Would really know why You need to optimize number of queries over summary execution time.

Comment: There is no need to go to SQL for a simple join, the ORM will do that for you.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the **prefetch_related** method for reversed foreignKey lookups. This won't actually reduce the number of SQL queries, but django will merge in python related comments and Topics.

In the docs : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Also, you should make sure to give different related_name to your fields, otherwise you'll have issues calling them :

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_comments')
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='topic_comments')
```

This way you can write a single line query (but 2 SQL hits) :

```
topics = Topic.objects.prefetch_related('topic_comments').select_related('author').all()
```

Then for example :

```
{% for topic in topics %}
  {% for comment in topic.topic_comments.all %}
    {{ ... }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Interesting, but maybe in some kind of list view.  It's details view here.

Comment: I do not use GenericViews, but I am pretty sure that this would work if you simply replace your actual queryset by the one I gave you.

Comment: @ Tanguy your correct, that approach will work fine, detail or list view.